# How do I modify and return an NSImage?

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

This is probably a newb question, but I'm having trouble understanding how to manipulate NSImage instances.

I'm trying to create a method that will take an NSImage (an icon), draw another NSImage over it (a checkmark), then return the modified NSImage instance.

I've looked at the section "Drawing to an Image" in the Cocoa Drawing Guide, but I still can't figure out how to return a modified NSImage.

Looking for something like:

```
(NSImage*) drawCheckbox:(NSImage*)originalImage {
    NSImage* checkbox = [NSImage imageNamed:@"checkbox"];

    // create and return new NSImage with checkbox drawn over originalImage
}
```

TIA!

Comment: As a general rule, it's preferable to draw both images on-demand, rather than attempt to composite them ahead of time

Comment: The main reason I want to create a new NSImage is I want to cache and reuse the image. There's only a handful of images I need to composite, but I'll need to reuse them repeatedly. I imagine performance will ultimately be better by creating a new NSImage?

Comment: NEVER imagine. Try it and measure

Comment: haha- yes- thank you for the advice. But in order to "try it and measure", I need to find out "how to modify and return an NSImage" so I can run empirical tests.

Comment: True. My logic is to do the easy thing and then simply measure to see if it's too slow

Answer (score 0):

First, make a copy of the original image. Then, draw into the new image as described in the documentation you mentioned. Finally, return your altered image using the `return` statement.